# How to show dynamic drawable using Picasso

Tags: android, android-drawable, picasso

I have some drawable generated dynamically from material design icons

```
  Drawable qq = new IconDrawable(context, FontAwesomeIcons.fa_qq).
                colorRes(R.color.qq).sizeRes(R.dimen.button_height_normal);
```

I want to show this Drawable using Picasso but when try to load this Drawable get an error because `Picasso load` accept only url for the Drawable and I can't get it or get it's `Resource Id`. 
there any way to make that ?

Comment: just use `View#setBackground` or `ImageView#setImageDrawable` etc

Comment: @pskink i want to display images using Picasso  not directly assign it to view or imageview

Comment: what does `"want to display images"` mean? you are not using `ImageView`s?

Comment: I use image view, but i mean display image in image view using Picasso

Comment: `"there any way to make that ?"` yes, as i said, use `ImageView#setImageDrawable(Drawable)`, you dont need picasso to show the `Drawable` on your `ImageView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a workaround as I've not seen the way to set directly a dynamically generated drawable. Picasso has the "error" and "placeholder" options that they both allow inputing a drawable so if you make the load to fail the Picasso will load the drawable (with you desired transformations, for instance):

```
Picasso.with(context).load("nothing").error(placeholder).placeholder(placeholder).into(this)
```

where **placeholder** is the drawable you want to load